# Find the upper element of the vector $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}5\\ \:2\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am asked to find the upper element of the vector  $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}5\\ \:2\end{pmatrix}$

The upper element is supposed to be the 1. coordinate of the upper value from the vector. I am not quite sure what that means.

The vector is formed from the eigenvectors from the matrix $ A = \begin{pmatrix}8&-18\\ 3&-7\end{pmatrix}$

I have calculated the property that $A = PDP^{-1} \to \begin{pmatrix}8&-18\\ 3&-7\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3&2\\ \:\:\:\:\:\:1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ \:\:\:\:\:\:0&-1^{\:}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\ \:\:\:\:\:\:-1&3\end{pmatrix}$

And from this I have managed to get $A^n = PD^nP^{-1} \to \begin{pmatrix}3\cdot \:2^n+2&-3\cdot \:2^{1+n}-6\\ 2^n+1&-2^{n+1}-3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3&2\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2^n&0\\ 0&-1^n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\ -1&3\end{pmatrix}$

This is where I am stuck now. How am I supposed to find the "upper element"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's something wrong here. If $A$ is a square $2\times 2$ matrix, then $A^n$ cannot be equal to a vector.

Comment: $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Mankind that is something I was wondering also. Maybe I have to ask my professor if there is an error somewhere else.

Comment: Surely, you must be missing something or made a typo (*or professor made a typo*)... Maybe the question was meant to be "*Find the upper element* **of $x$** *if* $A^nx = \binom{5}{2}$"

Comment: As a typesetting thing... what is up with all of these `\:\:\:\:\:\:` whitespaces in your matrices?  $\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ looks a lot better than $\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\\:\:\:\:\:\:1&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry I know it looks horrible. I copied from a calculator straight with less typing... I will be looking onto it!